# How to create BaseAdapter for RecyclerView with ViewBinding?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewbinding

I want to create a BaseAdapter class for RecyclerView with ViewBinding, but when I tried the following code:

```
    class SimpleListAdapter<T, K: ViewBinding>(
        private val itemBinding: K,
        val bindFun:(viewBinding:K, listType:T)->Unit
    ): RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleListAdapter.ViewHolder<K>>() {


        var list:List<T> = emptyList()

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder<K> {
            return ViewHolder(itemBinding)
        }

        override fun getItemCount()= list.size


        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder<K>, position: Int) {
            val listItem=list[position]
            bindFun(holder.binding,listItem)
        }

        class ViewHolder<K:ViewBinding>(val binding: K): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
    }

    class HabitListFragment : Fragment() {

        private  val viewModel: HabitListViewModel by lazy{
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(HabitListViewModel::class.java)
        }

        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                                  savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
            val itemBinding=HabitListItemBinding.inflate(inflater)

            val listAdapter=SimpleListAdapter<SummaryTumple,HabitListItemBinding>(itemBinding){
                    habitListItemBinding: HabitListItemBinding, summaryTumple: SummaryTumple ->
                        habitListItemBinding.desc.text=summaryTumple.description
                        habitListItemBinding.title.text=summaryTumple.title
            }

        /*....*/

        }

    }
```

I got an error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewHolder views must not be attached
>   when created. Ensure that you are not passing 'true' to the
>   attachToRoot parameter of LayoutInflater.inflate(..., boolean
>   attachToRoot)
>           at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6796)

I'm confused, and cannot figure out the cause. How should I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't attach your XML, but I had a similar problem which arose from not having `android:id="@+id/root"` on the root element of the layout.  So, when I referenced `binding.root`, it returned a view with a parent, which caused the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have imported the correct **ViewBinding** class

```
import androidx.viewbinding.ViewBinding
```

If you get an error then upgrade your Gradle version to minimum 7.0.0
**classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'**